# Move from SOAP::Lite to XML::Compile::SOAP

Tags: xml, perl, soap

So here's my [`SOAP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SOAP-Lite/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm) code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ 'debug' ];

my $req1 = SOAP::Lite->new(
    readable => 1,
    autotype => 0,
    proxy    => 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor',
);

$req1->requestMessage(
    \SOAP::Data->new(
        name => 'item',
        attr => { foo => '0' },
        value => \SOAP::Data->new(
            name => 'foo',
            value => 1,
        ),
     ),
);
```

It generates this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<requestMessage>
  <c-gensym9>
    <item foo="0">
      <foo>1</foo>
    </item>
  </c-gensym9>
</requestMessage>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I generate the same thing (without the gensym's) using [`XML::Compile::SOAP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-SOAP/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP.pod)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
cpan BERLE/SOAP-Simple-0.00_03.tar.gz
```

then

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Simple;
my $wsdlfile = '...';
my $soap = SOAP::Simple->new($wsdlfile);
print Dumper(
    $soap->requestMessage(
        item => [
            { foo => 1  },
        ],
    )
);
```

---

or see http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKOV/XML-Compile-SOAP-2.24/t/53wsdlrpclit.t and copy http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKOV/XML-Compile-SOAP-2.24/t/examples/rpc-literal/element.pl and use

```
schema2example -s element.wsdl -s type.wsdl -x requestMessage.xml
```

to generate a %request for element.pl, so in the end you end up with something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# general debugging of XML::Compile modules
#~ use Log::Report mode => 3;

# Data::Dumper is your friend in understanding the answer
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

# The features we use
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;  # we fake an HTTP server

#
# During initiation 'compile time'
#

my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new('element.wsdl');
my $call = $wsdl->compileClient('using_element'
#~   , transport_hook => \&fake_server # hook simulates a remote server at test
  );

#
# Reuse often at 'run time'
#

my %request =
 ( item =>
   [ { foo => 1}
   ]
 );

my $answer = $call->( requestMessage => \%request);

# Useful for debugging.  Also useful to report to syslog
#    my ($answer, $trace) = $call->(\%request);
#    $trace->printTimings;

# When you do not know how the answer is structured
#print Dumper $answer;

if($answer->{Fault})
{   print "Oops\n";
}
else
{   print "*** RESULT=$answer->{answer_via_element}{result}\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Once you're generating the xml you want, try it live

Comment: This example misses the foo="0" attribute